# Crystal Report column font set Dynamically based on a condition

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2008

[image: Crystal Report]

I am using Crystal Report for generating Reports.

I have to set the font size and color of "Test Result" column based on "Noramal Range" column.

if "Test Result" (12) is in range of "Normal Range"(12-13) then

size =15 and color =red

else

size =10 and color =Green

Both Columns are in Details section of Crystal Report and i have assigned value to it using set data source property of Crystal ( rpt.SetDataSource(ds1.Tables[0]))

I have used

```
 FieldObject field;

 field = rpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["TestResult1"] as FieldObject;

 Font fo = new Font("Arial Black", 15F, FontStyle.Bold);

 field.ApplyFont(fo);

 field.Color = Color.Red;
```

But this gets applied to the whole column and not to a particular Row.

Please Help.

Comment: yogesh dada , handi fodayala ja, crystal report kay roj chaluch rahil... ja Babu Genu chi handi pahayala

Comment: mi sandhyakali Ghatkopar la bharatatali sagalyat mothi dahihandi pahayala janare

Answer (score 2):

If you apply a condition in Detail section then the property will be applicable to all the records displayed in detail section, It is the functionality of crystal reports.

In your case if you want to do any formating to particular row then you need to include the `Testname` column in the condition so that the formating will be limited.